# Antonym of Objectification

Tags: vocabulary, antonyms

I am attempting to write a paper where I discuss how characters in one novel are objectified, while others in another novel are rendered sensations or are defined emotionally. Is there a word for the opposite of objectified? Sensitized? Can this word be applied to humans?

Comment: When you say "objectified" are you talking about Personification? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personification  or maybe Anthropomorphism? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism  I'm not sure what the opposite would be called, or even what an opposite would look like.  Do you have an example?

Comment: The opposite of 'objectified' would be 'treated as a (normal) human (being)'. Do we *need* for a word for that? There's no opposite of 'murdered'. You could say they are 'not objectified'.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian you've clearly made a mistake, this is 2020, inventing words is the name of the game

Comment: You may be asking for a *nuanced* description, as one that sees a character as an individual with good and bad, rather than a stick figure of limited dimension.

Comment: @小奥利奥 Lexicographers are a pushover these days. Time for some *pushback*!

Comment: There are many possible terms: "given agency", "rendered in three dimensions", or as Old Brixtonian says, something like "portrayed as human beings". Think about what you actually want to say.

Answer (score 0):

*Subjectification*, but with a health warning.

> to identify with (a subject) or interpret subjectively. - [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/subjectification)

The opposite of being the object is being the subject. This is true both in grammar, and more conceptually. Therefore, subjectification is the opposite of objectification.

[Published example](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/01425690600802907).

However, a health warning before you run off and use it, especially in a paper. It's a fairly recent construction coming out of translations of French continental philosophy in the 1980s, particularly Foucault. (Quick overview at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(philosophy))). As it's not in wide use, you would have to engage specifically with those thinkers in your essay, citing a definition and showing the link to your argument. That might be more impact on your paper than you intend.

Explaining with a phrase may also be more readable. You might say that these characters come across as thinking people with complex emotional lives, instead of things.